# "[: Binary: unexpected operator" message when updating rkhunter definitions on 15.10

Tags: gnome, binary, 15.10, rkhunter

After upgrading to Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 from 15.04 I have noticed that upon running the command:

```
sudo rkhunter --update
```

That I get this output:

```
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.2 ]

Checking rkhunter data files...
  Checking file mirrors.dat                                  [ No update ]
  Checking file programs_bad.dat                             [ No update ]
  Checking file backdoorports.dat                            [ No update ]
  Checking file suspscan.dat                                 [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/cn                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/de                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/en                                      [ No update ]
/usr/bin/rkhunter: 7439: [: Binary: unexpected operator
  Checking file i18n/tr                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/tr.utf8                                 [ No update ]
/usr/bin/rkhunter: 7439: [: Binary: unexpected operator
  Checking file i18n/zh                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/zh.utf8                                 [ No update ]
```

This is the relevant section of the log file:

```
[20:47:33] Checking rkhunter data files...
[20:47:33] Info: Created temporary file '/var/lib/rkhunter/tmp/rkhunter.upd.80Dxz4681c'
[20:47:33] Info: Created temporary file '/var/lib/rkhunter/tmp/mirrors.dat.TQulAoe7Ji'
[20:47:33] Info: The mirrors file has been rotated: /var/lib/rkhunter/db/mirrors.dat
[20:47:33] Info: Executing download command '/usr/bin/wget  -q -O "/var/lib/rkhunter/tmp/rkhunter.upd.80Dxz4681c" http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/1.3/mirrors.dat 2>/dev/null'
[20:47:33] Info: This version  : 2007060601
[20:47:34] Info: Latest version: 2007060601
[20:47:34] Checking file mirrors.dat                         [ No update ]
[20:47:34] Info: Executing download command '/usr/bin/wget  -q -O "/var/lib/rkhunter/tmp/rkhunter.upd.80Dxz4681c" http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/1.3/programs_bad.dat 2>/dev/null'
[20:47:34] Info: This version  : 2014042901
[20:47:34] Info: Latest version: 2014042901
[20:47:34] Checking file programs_bad.dat                    [ No update ]
[20:47:34] Info: Executing download command '/usr/bin/wget  -q -O "/var/lib/rkhunter/tmp/rkhunter.upd.80Dxz4681c" http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/1.3/backdoorports.dat 2>/dev/null'
[20:47:34] Info: This version  : 2010111401
[20:47:34] Info: Latest version: 2010111401
[20:47:34] Checking file backdoorports.dat                   [ No update ]
[20:47:34] Info: Executing download command '/usr/bin/wget  -q -O "/var/lib/rkhunter/tmp/rkhunter.upd.80Dxz4681c" http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/1.3/suspscan.dat 2>/dev/null'
[20:47:35] Info: This version  : 2009112901
[20:47:35] Info: Latest version: 2009112901
[20:47:35] Checking file suspscan.dat                        [ No update ]
[20:47:35] Info: Executing download command '/usr/bin/wget  -q -O "/var/lib/rkhunter/tmp/rkhunter.upd.80Dxz4681c" http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/1.3/i18n/1.4.2/i18n.ver 2>/dev/null'
[20:47:35] Info: This version  : 2009091601
[20:47:35] Info: Latest version: 2009091601
[20:47:35] Checking file i18n/cn                             [ No update ]
[20:47:35] Info: This version  : 2014010301
[20:47:35] Info: Latest version: 2014010301
[20:47:35] Checking file i18n/de                             [ No update ]
[20:47:35] Info: This version  : 2013112401
[20:47:35] Info: Latest version: 2013112401
[20:47:35] Checking file i18n/en                             [ No update ]
[20:47:35] Info: This version  : Binary file /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/tr matches
[20:47:35] Info: Latest version: 2014030201
[20:47:35] Checking file i18n/tr                             [ No update ]
[20:47:35] Info: This version  : 2014030201
[20:47:35] Info: Latest version: 2014030201
[20:47:35] Checking file i18n/tr.utf8                        [ No update ]
[20:47:35] Info: This version  : Binary file /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/zh matches
[20:47:35] Info: Latest version: 2009091601
[20:47:35] Checking file i18n/zh                             [ No update ]
[20:47:35] Info: This version  : 2009091601
[20:47:35] Info: Latest version: 2009091601
[20:47:35] Checking file i18n/zh.utf8                        [ No update ]
```

So what do these errors mean? Do I need to do anything about them? And should I report them?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
rkhunter:
  Installed: 1.4.2-3
  Candidate: 1.4.2-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.2-3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a stupid bug. I have added some`echo` in the script and here is the result:

In `/usr/bin/rkhunter: 7439` the script tries to compare

```
Binary file /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/tr matches
```

with

```
2014030201
```

per `-lt`

```
if [ $PROG_VERS -lt $LATEST_VERS ]; then
```

That means

```
PROG_VERS is not really a version number
```

The real problem is in this line

```
PROG_VERS=`grep ${GREP_OPT} '^[Vv]ersion:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' "${DB_PATH}/i18n/${LANGFILE}" 2>/dev/null | tail ${TAIL_OPT}1 | cut -d: -f2`
```

added another `echo` gives this

```
sudo grep  '^[Vv]ersion:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/tr 2>/dev/null | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f2
```

and this returns

```
Binary file /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/tr matches
```

Looks not really good.

The funny thing, all "binary files" are ISO-8859 text, e.g.

```
$ sudo file /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/tr
/var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/tr: ISO-8859 text
```

Let's check the content

```
$ sudo cat /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/tr
```

and we see

```
LOCK_USED:Kilitleme kullan�mda: zaman a��m� $1 saniye
LOCK_UNUSED:Kilitleme kullan�mda de�il
LOCK_WAIT:Kilit dosyas� bekleniyor
LOCK_FAIL:Kilit dosyas� al�namad�: rkhunter �al��mad�!
```

He guys and girls, that's not really ISO-8859. o_O

---

I tried

```
sudo -i
rm -r /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/*
```

without an effect. After a `sudo rkhunter --update` we have the same problem again, means, the downloaded files have the wrong encoding.

And now a really dirty hack. Convert the encoding for all files, e.g.

```
sudo iconv -f ISO-8859-14  /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/zh -t UTF-8 -o /var/lib/rkhunter/db/i18n/zh
```

and start the update again

```
% sudo rkhunter --update                                                                       
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.2 ]

Checking rkhunter data files...
  Checking file mirrors.dat                                  [ No update ]
  Checking file programs_bad.dat                             [ No update ]
  Checking file backdoorports.dat                            [ No update ]
  Checking file suspscan.dat                                 [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/cn                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/de                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/en                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/tr                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/tr.utf8                                 [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/zh                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/zh.utf8                                 [ No update ]
```

**But keep in mind, that's a hack and not a permanent solution**. You should write a bug report

Comment: Wow!  That's a good one...  (closing as "file bug report")

Comment: @Fabby: I think that's only if my report was an actual bug report, if it's me asking if this is a bug or not and whether or not I should file a report then I am not so sure about closing it as a bug report.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck and sounds like a duck...